# Generating Dynamic Labels in GraphView

Tags: android, android-graphview

I've used the GraphView library for drawing graphs is android. It works fine. The scroll and Zoom parts also work. But, I've used time label for the X axis. I can display the Date using CustomLabelFormatter, but want to improve it further. 
        Initially, just the dates should be displayed along X axis. On further zooming in, the Hour, and on further zooming, the minutes.
        I also want to control the zooming, i.e, no zooming in after a particular point.This is what I have now:

```
graphView.setCustomLabelFormatter(new CustomLabelFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String formatLabel(double value, boolean isValueX) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isValueX) {
                Date d = new Date((long) value);
                return (dateFormat.format(d));
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Labels are in the form:   May 08 09:20